# Save multiple values into column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to store multiple values retrieved from a JSONP request into my rails database so I can show the different results later.

I've created a function in my controller like this,

```
movieAdd.trailer(movie.id)
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.youtubeTrailer = response;
    console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)
```

This requests the `trailer` service in my movieService.js,

```
var service = {};
var baseUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
function httpPromise (url) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method:'JSONP',
    url: url
  })
    .success(function(data){
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}
service.trailer = function(youtube_link){
  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + youtube_link + '/videos?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942c**a28d7cadad4&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )
};
```

And I store the results in the `youtubeTrailer` scope.

Then I have a create function,

```
createMovie.create({
  release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
  youtube_link:   $scope.youtubeTrailer.key,
  imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
  title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
  image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
  movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
}).then(init);
```

I've added the param to my movies_controller.rb

```
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :youtube_trailer, :imdb_rating, :movie_id)
end
```

And I've created a column in my movies table

```
t.string   "youtube_trailer"
```

But when I check my movies.json it says `youtube_trailer":null`

To recap, I get this kind of output,

```
{"id":1893,"results":[
  {"id":"533ec65ac3a3685448000a24","iso_639_1":"en","key":"bD7bpG-zDJQ","name":"Trailer 1","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"533ec65ac3a3685448000a25","iso_639_1":"en","key":"UgDhFgSTPIw","name":"Trailer 2","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"}
]}
```

And I'm trying to store both `key` values in my database so I can use them later.

Comment: I'm not sure where movies.json comes from as I don't see that anywhere else, but a couple of suggestions:  1. Remove your API key from this post, you shouldn't share it with anyone;  2. Your request function is over-complicated, $http() already returns a promise, just return $http({...}) and don't bother deferring it twice.  3. It doesn't look like you're doing that, but your question makes it sound as if you are trying to stuff multiple values into a single table cell, which you should not do.

Comment: The `trailer` service does output multiple values because movies can have multiple trailers. I'm looking for a way to store all those values.

Comment: @Yang's answer is probably correct.  Your request data does not match the expected parameter name in your ruby controller.  As for the multiple outputs, as long as each of the trailers is in its own row in the database, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting `youtube_trailer` but create this field as `youtube_link`. Please try to match the variable names.

Comment: I've changed that but I think the problem is the value of `$scope.youtubeTrailer`. Because if I console.log that scope I get a object with the movie id, then inside that object is another object which has the key value. So I'm thinking the `$scope.youtubeTrailer` doesn't have the correct value to save.